# Java - Output from StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder

```
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder("abc");
StringBuilder b = a.append("de");
b = b.append("f").append("g");
System.out.println("a=" + a);
System.out.println("b=" + b);
```

Why is the output of both a &b is the same?

Comment: `StringBuilder b = a.append("de"); ` I think you copy the reference in memory to b. Then the appending will applied to both because both referencing the same object in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Let me break up the line `StringBuilder b = a.append("de");`

Here `a.append("de")` means

`a = a + "de"`. `ie a = "abcde"`

then `StringBuilder b = a.append("de") = a;`

Now StringBuilder `b` and `a` have same reference.

To avoid this issue you have to create a new `StringBuilder` object for `b`.

Comment: Thank You. You have explained so well!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder("abc");
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(a.append("de"));
b = b.append("f").append("g");
System.out.println("a=" + a);
System.out.println("b=" + b);
```

The output will now be:

```
a=abcde
b=abcdefg
```

In your case 'b' is also just a reference to 'a'. Which means 'a' and 'b' are referencing to same object. Any change in one will reflect onto the other.

Answer (score 0):

In line 2, when you say "StringBuilder b = a.append("de")" you're essentially linking both of them together. So, the 2 of them are the same at that point. When you do a.append("de"), that line has 2 functions. One is to add "de" to the StringBuilder a. The second is to set StringBuilder b to String builder a. So, since both of them are set to the same thing, the result comes out the same.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder is **not** immutable.  It only returns an instance of itself as a convenience so you can chain methods.  So `a` and `b` refer to the same instance as shown here.

```
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder("abc");
StringBuilder b = a.append("de");
b = b.append("f").append("g");
System.out.println("a=" + a);
System.out.println("b=" + b);

System.out.println("a = " + System.identityHashCode(a));
System.out.println("b = " + System.identityHashCode(b));
System.out.println(a == b);
```

Prints

```
a=abcdefg
b=abcdefg
a = 925858445
b = 925858445
true
```